# Read data from Firebase

Tags: database, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I'm using Firebase for my Android app, I want read datas. In particular I want to select an user with a specific id. When I use the debugger it seems that the code doesn't execute the onDataChange() instruction.

```
private User readUserById(){
    final User u = new User("","","");
    Query query = mDatabaseReferences.child("users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                u.setId(ds.child("id").getValue(User.class).getId());
                u.setNumber((ds.child("number").getValue(User.class).getNumber()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return u;
}

private void initFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReferences = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
}

 public void sendCode(View v){

    id= id.getText().toString();
    readUserById();
        phoneNumber = phoneText.getText().toString();
        if (phoneNumber.equals("") || id.equals("")) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert a nickname and a valid phone number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        } else {
            setUpVerificationCallbacks();

            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber,
                    60,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    this,
                    verificationCallbacks
            );
        }
  //  }

}
```

Using the debugger I've seen that the 'id' value is correct.

I used Firebase documentation for sendCode(), the user registration works correctly, just like the sms sending. I want to check if the nickname already exists, and the value is in the 'id' Textview. I call the sendCode() through a button.

I've tried in this way but doesn't work. Running with the debugger the result of user is null

```
private User readUserByName(){
    final User[] user = {new User()};
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("users").child(nick).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                user[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Log.d("Tag", user[0].toString());
            }
            else
                Log.e("Tag","No such user exists");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return user[0];
}
```

[This is how I save the User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NMi6.png)

[I've launched the app with the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrHId.png)

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Comment: I added the structure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `users` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference testRef = rootRef.child("users").child("test");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
        String idName = dataSnapshot.child("idName").getValue(String.class);
        String number = dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", id + " / " + idName + " / " + number);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
testRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
test / f70eb... / number
```

Comment: It does not work 
It still doesn't execute the onDataChange()
I've added a new image

Comment: What do you have un your logcat? Do you see the above output?

Comment: There's nothing, it seems (and i think) that onDataChange() is not executed

Comment: Shoe me your entire class. There is something else wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that :

1. node "users" directly under root node.
2. You already know the id of the user and this id contains all the information under **User.class**
3. You only want to read a user, if exists in database.
4. All the getters and setter exists in User.class and a Public empty constructor exists

Here is how you should do it

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.child("users").ref(id).addListenerforSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

And in Listener's OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snap);

```
if(snap.exists()){
      user = snap.getValue(User.class);
     Log.d("Tag",user.toString());
    }
else
      Log.e("Tag","No such user exists");
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not even syntactically correct. Why using Array of Users? Also, you should keep "nick" in double quotations. The Answer above is just for reference, you must have enough skills to implement it in your Code

Comment: Android Studio change the variable User in final User[]